# Vuetify menu inside list item - clickable area is not all the way to the edges

Tags: vuetify.js

For each v-list-item I want a v-menu to pop-up on click.

https://codepen.io/hobbeschild/pen/JjKPagg

There are some places around the border of each list item where the styling indicates that you can click, but a click does not do anything.

How can I ensure that the clickable area is maximised to the whole of the list item?

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
      class="mx-auto"
      max-width="300"
      tile
    >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item-group
          color="primary"
        >
          <v-list-item
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="i"
          >
            <v-menu absolute>
              <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-list-item-content v-on="on">
                  <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
               </template>
              <v-card>
                <v-card-text>hello</v-card-text>
              </v-card>
            </v-menu>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    item: 1,
    items: [
      { text: 'Real-Time', icon: 'mdi-clock' },
      { text: 'Audience', icon: 'mdi-account' },
      { text: 'Conversions', icon: 'mdi-flag' },
    ],
  }),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by the Vuetify Discord team:

Them: "the list item should be the activator, not the list item content"

Me:  "that does sort the clickable area.  But that means the menu is outside the v-for loop.  What if I want to print something from the v-for loop in the menu?"

They put the v-for on the menu and it works perfectly:

https://codepen.io/kaelwd/pen/QWELJmw?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card
            class="mx-auto"
            max-width="300"
            tile
            >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-item-group
                           color="primary"
                           >
          <v-menu 
                  absolute 
                  v-for="(item, i) in items"
                  :key="i"
                  >
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
              <v-list-item v-on="on">
                <v-list-item-content>
                  <v-list-item-title v-text="item.text"></v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
              </v-list-item>
            </template>
            <v-card>
              <v-card-text>something from the list item? {{ item.text }}</v-card-text>
            </v-card>
          </v-menu>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```